# loading of user controls around 19 controls one by one in web page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

how to do loading of user controls around 19 user controls one by one in web page so that i have access to the loaded user control when other controls are loading and appended  simultaneously in a single web page

Comment: welcome to SO. Do you want to know how to load user controls. Or do you want to add it one after one. What the user control contains.

Comment: Thanks shekhar,I want to load user control one by one.

Comment: If you add these controls from C# or add it statically by placing it to your page, in both the cases all the control will load first and then the page will render. The better appoach would be create handler and call it from jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Have about 19 UpdatePanels in the page. Have a Timer in each of the control which will trigger the loading of the UserControl. In this way, each of the Usercontrol gets loaded upon the Timer event and the user can work with it when it is loaded.

Since a web browser can have 6 concurrent AJAX requests, ensure that your timer sets off at regular intervals.